# how to read and write non-fixed-length structs to biniary file c++

Tags: c++, vector, struct, file-io, cstdio

I have vector of structs:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint64_t id = 0;
    std::string name;
    std::vector<uint64_t> data;
} entry;
```

That I want to write to file:

```
FILE *testFile = nullptr;
testFile = fopen("test.b", "wb");
```

However the normal method for read/write

```
fwrite(vector.data(), sizeof vector[0], vector.size(), testFile);
fread(vector.data(), sizeof(entry), numberOfEntries, testFile);
```

does not work as the size of entry can vary wildly depending on the contents of

```
std::string name;
std::vector<uint64_t> data;
```

so I would like methods and pointers about how to do read/writing of this data to/from files.

Comment: Write it element by element and include information about how many entries the vector has and how many characters/bytes the string has. Trying to save the memory representation of a struct/class usually won’t work well, and definitely won’t work when there are non-basic datatypes involved.

Comment: Key word for further research: Serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with non-fixed size data it's important to keep track of the size somehow. You can simply specify the amount of fixed size elements or byte size of whole structure and calculate needed values when reading the struct. I'm in favour of the first one though it can sometimes make debugging a bit harder.

Here is an example how to make a flexible serialization system.

```cpp
struct my_data
{
   int a;
   char c;
   std::vector<other_data> data;
}

template<class T>
void serialize(const T& v, std::vector<std::byte>& out)
{
   static_assert(false, "Unsupported type");
}

template<class T>
requires std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<T>
void serialize(const T& v, std::vector<std::byte>& out)
{
   out.resize(std::size(out) + sizeof(T));
   std::memcpy(std::data(out) + std::size(out) - sizeof(T), std::bit_cast<std::byte*>(&v), sizeof(T));
}

template<class T>
void serialize<std::vector<T>>(const std::vector<T>& v, std::vector<std::byte>& out)
{
   serialize<size_t>(std::size(v), out); // add size
   for(const auto& e : v)
      serialize<T>(v, out);
}

template<>
void serialize<my_data>(const my_data& v, std::vector<std::byte>& out)
{
   serialize(v.a, out);
   serialize(v.c, out);
   serialize(v.data, out);
}

// And likewise you would do for deserialize

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::byte> data;
   my_data a;
   serialize(a, data);

   // write vector of bytes to file
}
```

This is a tedious job and there are already libraries that do it for you like [Google's Flatbuffers](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers), [Google's Protobuf](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf) or a single header [BinaryLove3](https://github.com/RedSkittleFox/BinaryLove3). Some of them work out of the box with aggregate types (meaning all member variables are public). Here is an example of BinaryLove3 in action.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <list>

#include "BinaryLove3.hpp"

struct foo
{
    uint32_t v0 = 3;
    uint32_t v1 = 2;
    float_t v2 = 2.5f;
    char v3 = 'c';
    struct
    {
        std::vector<int> vec_of_trivial = { 1, 2, 3 };
        std::vector<std::string> vec_of_nontrivial = { "I am a Fox!", "In a big Box!" };
        std::string str = "Foxes can fly!";
        std::list<int> non_random_access_container = { 3, 4, 5 };
    } non_trivial;
    struct
    {
        uint32_t v0 = 1;
        uint32_t v1 = 2;
    } trivial;
};

auto main() -> int32_t
{
    foo out = { 4, 5, 6.7f, 'd', {{5, 4, 3, 2}, {"cc", "dd"}, "Fly me to the moon..." , {7, 8, 9}}, {3, 4} };
    auto data = BinaryLove3::serialize(bobux);
    
    foo in;
    BinaryLove3::deserialize(data, in);
    return int32_t(0);
}
```